# Rename column that is set as index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, stock

I am working with script that pulls stock data from yahoo, in order to use it I need to change the column names so that they are all lower case. This works fine on all other columns except "Date" which is not changing for some reason. I tried renaming the columns before `set_index` but then the script stops saving the csv's.

heres the line to change names

```
df.rename(columns={'Date':'date',
                          'High':'high',
                          'Low':'low',
                          'Open':'open',
                          'Close':'close',
                          'Volume':'volume',
                          'Adj Close':'adj close'}, 
                 inplace=True)
```

and heres what it looks like in the code

```
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
    start = dt.datetime(2010, 6, 8)
    end = dt.datetime.now()
    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            try:
                df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
                df.reset_index(inplace=True)
                df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
                df.rename(columns={'Date':'date',
                          'High':'high',
                          'Low':'low',
                          'Open':'open',
                          'Close':'close',
                          'Volume':'volume',
                          'Adj Close':'adj close'}, 
                 inplace=True)
                df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
                time.sleep(2)
            except:
                continue
        else:
            

            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
```

after I updated (tried)

```
            try:
                df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
                df.reset_index(inplace=True)
                df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
                df.rename(columns={'High':'high',
                     'Low':'low',
                     'Open':'open',
                     'Close':'close',
                     'Volume':'volume',
                     'Adj Close':'adj close'}, 
           index = {'Date':'date'}, 
           inplace=True)
                df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

and then this

```
                df.rename(columns={'High':'high',
                     'Low':'low',
                     'Open':'open',
                     'Close':'close',
                     'Volume':'volume',
                     'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True) 
                df.rename(index = {'Date':'date'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For renaming indexes, you have to do

```
 df.rename(columns={'High':'high',
                     'Low':'low',
                     'Open':'open',
                     'Close':'close',
                     'Volume':'volume',
                     'Adj Close':'adj close'},  
           inplace=True)

df.index.rename('date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I just put update on code above, I did as you say but it is renaming all columns except the "date" column. I think this is because it is using it as the index and not considering it its own column, i've also tried making it a new function and renaming that way, but it doesnt change it

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it more verbose. Can you try this?

Comment: So I tried to format it a few different ways and change the order, but it doesn't seem to want to work. I added 2 ways I tried in the last edit to question.

Comment: This should do the job for you.